# VS Code IDE's shrink selection feature not working on mac os x

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to use the shrink selection feature of visual studio code IDE on mac osx. I am using it on javascript code blocks and tried using both the short cut as well as through the command palette.  What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: You probably have an override application like `spectacle`.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is confirmed to be working as expected for version 0.10.8.

Couple things you could be doing wrong.

- Do you have the latest stable version 0.10.8? You can find out in the About menu.
- Do you have another application overriding the key bindings? I saw an issue running spectacle on OS X. Once I disabled spectacle shrinking worked as expected.
- Are you trying to shrink a block of code that isn't shrinkable? For example the code below doesn't shrink immediately. I have to run shrink multiple times before it selects outside of the object block, which I'm not sure is intended or not.

  ```
  { data: 'category' },
  { data: 'displayName' },
  { data: 'lastUpdated' },
  { data: 'publisher' },
  { data: 'installs' },
  { data: 'description' }, 
  { data: 'tags' },
  ```